# AJAX not posting to WebMethod

Tags: c#, ajax, file-upload, webmethod

The Form:

```
<form action="upload-document.aspx" onsubmit="sendAndClose();" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

The AJAX:

```
    function sendAndClose() {
        currentUrl = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + location.pathname;

        var data = new FormData();
        var file = $("#fileToUpload")[0].files[0];

        data.append("name", file.name);
        data.append("size", file.size);
        data.append("type", file.type);
        data.append("file", file);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: currentUrl + '/Persist',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function () {
                parent.$.fancybox.close();
            },
            error: function (request, error) {
                alert("[" + error + "] - FAIL: " + request.responseText);
                parent.$.fancybox.close();
            }
        });
    }
```

The Code-Behind:

```
[WebMethod]
public static bool Persist(object data)
{
    return true;
}
```

when the form is submitted, it runs the ajax and goes straight to the error callback before entering the webmethod. can anybody tell me why?

also, after the 'var file' I had an alert to show the files name, size, etc... so it gets the file, the problem is that ajax is refusing to comunicate with the code-behind.

Comment: If you run Fiddler with the request what response do you get...? http://fiddler2.com/

Comment: Annotate the method as `[HttpPost]`.

Comment: Calil: not using mvc: theres no HttpPostAttribute

Comment: Hibbert: no idea what that is

Comment: Can I check the `Persist` method is on an ASPX page and not and ASCX user-control?

Comment: I have resolved this problem, i'd post it here but stackoverflow.com wont let me! thanks for everyone though.

Comment: @user2366528 - I've added my thoughts based on your answer to my question. However, you can post your own fix here. Just post your own Answer (at the bottom of this page) explaining what you did. It is still valid as other people may want to achieve the same things and hit the same issue. It is perfectly valid to do so and will help the community!

Comment: @user2366528 - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking

Comment: @user2366528 How did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem that was solved by adding this parameter in the ajax function :

```
traditional: true
```

So try this code for your AJAX call :

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: currentUrl + '/Persist',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        traditional: true,
        success: function () {
            parent.$.fancybox.close();
        },
        error: function (request, error) {
            alert("[" + error + "] - FAIL: " + request.responseText);
            parent.$.fancybox.close();
        }
    });
```

Comment: im sorry but i wouldnt know if it works, ive already changed my whole code. tyvm though!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot invoke a webmethod like `http://localhost:40899/upload-document.aspx/Persist`. The currentUrl is incorrect.

Comment: I already used the same logic to post from ajax to webmethods and they all worked since today. only difference is that this time its a file im trying to send.

Comment: I have resolved this problem, i'd post it here but stackoverflow.com wont let me! thanks though.

Comment: @user2366528 Can you at least explain the fix for solution at a high level? This would help.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from my question in the comments section I would add that your `public static bool Persist...` method **MUST** be in the page (ASPX) and not a user-control (ASCX).

This is because the page (ASPX) is "visible" to the outside world via a URL whereas a user-control (ASCX) is only used on the server to build up the page not a URI in its own right, and therefore not accessible to external callers.

If you need to call the method in the user-control you will need to move your `Persist` method (with `WebMethod` attribute) to your page (ASPX) and then make a call from that method into your user-control (ASCX).